# Persistance with a remastersys ISO on a USB pendrive

Tags: boot, iso, remastersys

I'm trying to create a bootable ISO of Ubuntu 11.04 using remastersys's backup option.

Ubuntu's Make Startup Disk utility allows me to create a bootable USB drive with this ISO, but the option for using part of the USB drive to store documents/settings is grayed out.

Not surprisingly, creating the bootable USB drive in this way does not offer persistance (files/settings changes not preserved between reboots).

Does anyone know how I can create a bootable USB drive using this ISO *with* persistance?

Comment: Use Unetbootin.

Answer (score 1):

You need a larger usb drive. At some point along the line, Ubuntu started requiring the persistent drive be a minimum of 1gb. If your distro leaves less than 1gb of free space on the usb drive you are using, it will be grayed out.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same, but I noticed that was because I had deleted all the partitions.
In the Startup Disk Creator, if the size option is gray, select the USB key and click on **Erase**. It will create a partition and the disk space size slider will be enabled.